# Build fails when importing vite module from webpack

Tags: webpack, vite, babel-loader, esbuild

I want to use Vite module to provide Vue SFC Loader feature in webpack.

So, we define the vite import as follows:

```
// vue-loader.js
import { preview } from 'vite';
```

However, the following sub-dependency compilation errors occurred:

```
Compiled with problems:

WARNING in ./node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js 1798:8-28

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression


WARNING in ./node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js 1865:15-32

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pnpapi' in 'C:\Dev\SAMPLE\vue2-webpack-template_230207\node_modules\vite\node_modules\esbuild\lib'


WARNING in ./node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js 35092:23-65

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression


ERROR in ./node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.d.ts

[tsl] ERROR
      TS18002: The 'files' list in config file 'tsconfig.json' is empty.


ERROR in ./node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.d.ts

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: error while parsing tsconfig.json
    at Object.loader (C:\Dev\SAMPLE\vue2-webpack-template_230207\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:17:18)
```

I don't know what the problem.

Using the vite import in webpack keeps giving me subdependency issues, could you please tell me why the vite import is not available?

Comment: It is difficult to answer without a whole project context

Comment: I’ve uploaded a sample project to [GitHub](https://github.com/dj6316/vue-webpack-template-sample).